# error event not triggering after server is shutdown/reset in ChatClient

Tags: javascript, react-native, sockets, websocket

I'm using this [chat client](https://github.com/ido-ofir/chat-client) with a React-Native app. Everything works fine except for the error event when something happens to the server. This is because I need to handle a re-connect strategy for the chat.

The library is supposed to throw an "error" event when this happens, so I'm listening to it like this:

```
   // Handle errors across the chat client
   this._chatClient.on('error', (data) => {
      ErrorHandler.log(`Chat Client error: ${data}`);
   });
```

But is not passing through. I even added a `onError` in the chat client constructor as the lib mentions, within the options param, but it's not being overridden nor called ever when something wrong happens.

Any idea on what could be the reason or if I'm missing anything? Should I also emit an event from the server-side? But how if the server is already down due to an unexpected issue?

Comment: Have you set `chatClient.options.log` to `true`? can you see error on console? [To trigger this](https://github.com/ido-ofir/chat-client/blob/master/index.js#L65)

Comment: Yes, right now is on false, but I have the same client but slightly modified with some other stuff i needed, whenever i put a breakpoint is not even entering in the error function.

Comment: Okay i was able to find it, it was the "close" event, not "error" the one being triggered. Pretty strange. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the event being triggered when the chat client is shutdown is "close" and not "error" event. Now it works. Hope this helps someone.